# How to programmatically set the upper text across all Apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I will word this question embarrassingly awkward and primitive as I have spent ten minutes searching for the answer and failed miserably. Please help/nudge to resolve!

**Desired IOS Feature**

Setting the upper navigation bar over all Apps to a custom color and text value that navigates to a specific App when tapped

**Example**

The App *SleepCycle* when it is set to Alarm-Clock mode, and when the User is in any other App other than *SleepCycle*. The top of the screen then becomes red with the text '*SleepCycle*' and when you single-tap it you navigate to *SleepCycle*

[image]

**Question**

What is this feature called and how do you programmatically implement it?

Comment: iOS will do this when your app is using certain features in the background such as accessing the microphone (red) or location (blue)

Answer (score 0):

When I've dabbled with this in the past, the hack(?) I used was to register as a Voice Over IP / audio app in Background Modes. WARNING: I have never tried to ship such an app to the App Store, as it seemed like a dubious approach.

Comment: I'll hold off investigation on this answer here for the moment, sounds immense and risky for a newb like me to explore! ;0